# Getting error when overloading << operator

Tags: c++, vector, operator-overloading, overloading

I have a Class called "Vector". It consists of two private fields: `std::vector<double> coordinates` and `int len`. Method`dim()` returns `len`.

I am overloading operator `<<` like that:

```
friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os,  Vector& vec ) 
{
    std:: cout << "(";
    for ( int i = 0; i < vec.dim(); i++ ) {
        if ( i != vec.dim()-1){
            os << vec[i] << ", ";
        } else {
            os << vec[i];
        }
    }
    os << ')';
    return os;
}
```

An operator `+` like that:

```
friend Vector operator +(Vector& first, Vector& second)
{
    if(first.dim() != second.dim()){
        throw std::length_error{"Vectors must be the same size"};
    }else {
        Vector localVec(first.dim()); // same as {0,0,0...,0} - first.dim() times 
        for (int i = 0; i < first.dim(); i++){
            localVec[i] = first[i] + second[i];
        }
        return localVec;
    }
}
```

And operator `[]` like that:

```
double& operator[](int index)
{
    return this->coordinates[index];
}
```

And here's the problem:

```
Vector x{1,2,4};
Vector y{1,2,3};
    
Vector z = x + y; 
std:: cout << z; // it works perfectly fine - (2, 4, 7)

std:: cout << x + y; // it gives me an error
```

- could not match 'unique_ptr<type-parameter-0-2, type-parameter-0-3>' against 'Vector'
  operator<<(basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& __os, unique_ptr<_Yp, _Dp> const& __p)

It seems to me that this error is related to parameter `Vector& vec` , but I don't know whether it's right and what should I do to fix it. If anyone could give me a hint (or tell me what I should read more about) - I would be very grateful.

Here's full code:

```
 class Vector
{
    private:
        std::vector <double> coordinates;
        int len;
    public:
        Vector(): len{0}, coordinates{} {};
        Vector(std::initializer_list <double> coordinates_): len{static_cast <int>( coordinates_.size())}, coordinates{coordinates_} {}
        Vector(int len) : len{len} {
            for(int i = 0; i < len; i++){
                coordinates.push_back(0);
            }
        }
        int dim() const
        {
            return this->len;
        }

        double& operator[](int index)
        {
            return this->coordinates[index];
        }

        friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os,  Vector& vec ) 
        {
            std:: cout << "(";
            for ( int i = 0; i < vec.dim(); i++ ) {
                if ( i != vec.dim()-1){
                    os << vec[i] << ", ";
                } else {
                    os << vec[i];
                }
            }
            os << ')';
            return os;
        }

        friend Vector operator +(Vector& first, Vector& second)
        {
            if(first.dim() != second.dim()){
                throw std::length_error{"Vectors must be the same size"};
            }else {
                Vector localVec(first.dim());
                for (int i = 0; i < first.dim(); i++){
                    localVec[i] = first[i] + second[i];
                }
                return localVec;
            }
        }
};
```

Comment: please post a [mcve]. The error complains about a unique_ptr in your real code, but in the code you posted there is none

Comment: fwiw, the mentioning of unique_ptr was just the beginning of a long list of `<<` overloads the compiler checked but none of them matched.

Comment: the interesting part of the message you left out: "source>:63:12: error: no match for 'operator<<' (operand types are 'std::ostream' {aka 'std::basic_ostream<char>'} and 'Vector')"

Comment: You should be more consistent in your coding guidelines.  Prefer not to use `this->` sequence more.  You proved you don't need it, in the constructor and operator+.

Comment: @BorisBorais On a side note: inside your `operator<<`, `std:: cout << "(";` should be `os << '(';` instead.

Comment: Never use lvalue reference in sake of optimization (instead of passing by value) use const reference instead. Especially that in modern C++ and properly written code passing by value can be easilty more efficient than passing by reference.

Comment: okay , thank you for your advice. all books I've read encouraged me to pass by reference for optimisation =)

Comment: @BorisBorais it is either a bad book or (which is more likely) you did not read it carefully - using **const** reference is the common practice to avoid copying significantly large object when passing it as an argument. You use lvlaue aka non-const reference only when you have intention to modify object which is passed to the function from outside scope.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A temporary cannot bind to a non-const reference argument. You are missing `const` in at least two places. Most importantly here:

```
friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Vector& vec ) 
                                                // ^^
```

And there should a `const` overload of `operator[]`

Comment: It works perfectly fine , thank you! I should read more about temporaries and rlvalues...

Comment: @BorisBorais primarily you should make anything `const` that can be `const`.

Answer (score 6):

> `friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os,  Vector& vec)`

This signature doesn't accept rvalues, and this is why the error happens for your temporary result here:

> `std:: cout << x + y;`

Change the second parameter into `const Vector& vec` or provide an overload with an r-value reference parameter.

```
friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Vector& vec);
```

Comment: I'm always getting messed when it's up to rlvalues... thank you!!!

Comment: @BorisBorais no you are messed because you do not provide const correctness.